# Remove tooltip of QAction when add it to QToolBar in Qt

Tags: qt, tooltip, qaction

I added a `QAction` on a `QToolBar`, but I can't remove a tooltip from the button.

I tried to overide `event`, `eventfilter` using `event->type == Qt::Tooltip` but it didn't help.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why it happens

When you add an action on a toolbar:

1. It creates a `QToolButton`
2. Calls `QToolButton::setDefaultAction` passing the action as an argument.
3. This method calls `setToolTip(action->toolTip());`
4. `action->toolTip()` returns whether `tooltip` or if the tooltip is empty it returns `text`. Thus you'll always have some tooltip on the button.

### What to do

Using the explanation above you can think of lots of ways to solve the problem.

For example, when `QToolbar` is created (and possibly shown) use `toolbar->findChildren<QToolButton*>` to find the buttons:

```
foreach(QToolButton* button, toolbar->findChildren<QToolButton*>())
{
  button->setToolTip(QString());
}
```

Note: when you change a text of an action, the appropriate button will recreate the tooltip. You can use an event filter for a button to process the tooltip event.

EDIT: added an **example**:

`Ui` contains a toolbar with an action.

```
testwindow::testwindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    foreach(QToolButton* button, ui.mainToolBar->findChildren<QToolButton*>())
    {
        button->setToolTip(QString());
    }
}
```

When you change an action (text, enabling state...) a `QToolButton` updates a tooltip. In this case you need to prevent the tooltip appearance permanently:

```
testwindow::testwindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    foreach(QToolButton* button, ui.mainToolBar->findChildren<QToolButton*>())
    {
        button->installEventFilter(this);
    }
}

bool testwindow::eventFilter(QObject* o, QEvent* e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
    {
      return true;
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(o, e);
}
```

Comment: Sr but I not using button in QToolBar, I create it in .ui file. I add QAction to QToolBar in ui file. And I try eventFilter(QObject,QEvent) but tooltip not disappear.

Comment: It doesn't matter how do you add an action to a `QToolBar` using ui or from the code.

Comment: thanks for your help,I'm trying it, but tooltip still appear.

Comment: It does work. I added a working example. You can try to test it.

Comment: Ok, Ezee, because I not clean and rebuild. Thanks so much.

Comment: if have 1 action isn't enable, it still show tooltip. How to disappear all tooltip when action isn't enable ?.

Comment: As I said a button recreates a tooltip when an action is changed. To handle all changes install an event filter on each button and return `true` when a tooltip event comes.

Comment: Added another example